# How can I export an excel worksheet as image?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm triying to generate an image from an excel worksheet. After a lot of research, I'm using the following code, but at some point I get an exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Prueba
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            try
            {
                Workbook w = a.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\SCRATCH\Libro2.xlsx");
                Worksheet ws = w.Sheets["Report"];
                ws.Protect(Contents: false);
                Range r = ws.Range["B2:H20"];
                r.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
                a.DisplayAlerts = false;

                // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)
                ChartObject chartObj = ws.ChartObjects().Add(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height); 

                chartObj.Activate();
                Chart chart = chartObj.Chart;
                chart.Paste();
                chart.Export(@"C:\SCRATCH\image.JPG", "JPG");
                chartObj.Delete();
                w.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            } 
            finally
            {
                a.Quit();                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Office 2013, 64 bits, Windows 7 64 and .Net 4.5.

Comment: What exception do you get, and on which line?

Comment: Below the line with the comment, I get what the comment says

Comment: Why not export the image directly from the clipboard?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c2a05de-c680-4515-898a-e92f28eddbf9/retrieve-image-from-clipboard-and-save-it-in-different-formats

Comment: Good idea. Already tried it and the problem is that nothing is returned by Clipboard.GetDataObject() even if I can paste it into MS Paint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me in a WinForms project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ios = System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClipBoardTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ExportRangeAsJpg()
        {
            Excel.Application xl;

            xl = (Excel.Application)ios.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

            if (xl == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Excel !!");
                return;
            }

            Excel.Workbook wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook;
            Excel.Range r = wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A1:E10"];
            r.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen,
                           Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

             if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
            {
                IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
                    this.pict1.Image = image;
                    image.Save(@"C:\_Stuff\test\sample.jpg",
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No image in Clipboard !!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clipboard Empty !!");
            }  
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportRangeAsJpg();
        }



    }
}
```

For a console app you need to see also: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/c/use-clipboard-copypaste-in-c-console-application/

Comment: Your answer is OK. But for some reason I'm getting an exception. I have opened a new question to treat this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850999/how-can-i-avoid-this-exception-when-copying-a-selected-range-in-excel

Comment: Note that you don't need to use the clipboard -- you can just cast the Workbook to an IDataObject, and get the Bitmap format for the selected sheet.  Also Jpeg is a horrible choice for an Excel screen cap (that format is optimized for photography, for a purpose like this, Jpeg will introduce visual artifacts) -- encode the image as a PNG instead.

Comment: I try to use your code for my console app, but "Clipboard.GetDataObject()" got a null. Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a `Chart` object. Calling `CopyPicture()` on the `Range` puts the image on the system clipboard. You can finish it off in as little as two steps, if you want:

```
        Workbook w = a.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\SCRATCH\Libro2.xlsx");
        Worksheet ws = w.Sheets["Report"];
        ws.Protect(Contents: false);
        Range r = ws.Range["B2:H20"];
        r.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Clipboard.GetImage());
        image.Save(@"C:\SCRATCH\image.png");

        // charting code, replaced with the above 
               /* ChartObject chartObj = ws.ChartObjects().Add(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height); 

                chartObj.Activate();
                Chart chart = chartObj.Chart;
                chart.Paste();
                chart.Export(@"C:\SCRATCH\image.JPG", "JPG");
                chartObj.Delete(); */
```

EDIT: Leaving all the error checking and flow control to you, but it would be wise of course to (at least) use the `ContainsImage()` method of the `Clipboard` class before trying to access it's content.

Comment: Same comment as above -- no need to overwrite the clipboard -- just cast the Workbook object as an IDataObject directly -- this works.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier in **VBA** :

```
Sub PictureSaver()
    Dim ch As Chart
    Charts.Add
    Set ch = ActiveChart
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A1:D4").Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ch.Select
    ch.Paste
    ch.Export Filename:="sample.jpg"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ch.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I use VBA standalone? I ask because I need to do more stuff like query a database and other operations

Comment: **A great question!**  It might be possible to modify the script to run "outside" the workbook...........I would open a new post to ask the question.....

Answer (score 0):

```
                    //station--> excel file path
                    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    var xls = app.Workbooks.Open(Station,false,true);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = xls.Worksheets;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= sheets.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = sheets[j];
                        string startRange = "A1";
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range endRange = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range(startRange, endRange);
                        range.Rows.AutoFit();
                        range.Columns.AutoFit();
                        range.Copy();

                        BitmapSource image = Clipboard.GetImage();
                        FormatConvertedBitmap fcbitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(image, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + j + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                            encoder.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.On;
                            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(fcbitmap));
                            encoder.Save(fileStream);
                        }
                        Set_Cavnas(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  +j + ".jpg");
                        File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  +j + ".jpg");
                    }
                    //release resources
                    app.DisplayAlerts = false;
                    xls.Close(false);
                    app.Quit();
                    GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).