# Read data from excel with image column using c# .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel, filereader

I want to create one file that display data of my excel file..
There are columns in FileData.xlsx file [Id Name    Age Gender  Designation Date Of Birth   Phone Number    Photo]

I need image too with my code and i want to display all the data using html or any other views i tried simple html

here is my code that displays all data except image...
Important: you can not take image path from local you need to insert image on excel file

Comment: Hey, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759417/how-can-i-export-an-excel-worksheet-as-image
Can u show us, what you have done so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Saiko hi i provided code to you...please check

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apologize for the following code I provided as a quick solution. As an apprentice in training, I am still in the process of learning and developing my programming skills. I acknowledge that the code may not be as refined or efficient as expected. Maybe someone can take use of it and make a better and cleaner answer out of of it.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;

using LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext;

namespace Excel2HTML

{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            string excelFilePath = @"C:\Users\Benne\Desktop\parse.xlsx";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelFilePath);

            List<string> base64Strings = GetImageAsBase64(fileInfo);

            Convert2Html(fileInfo, base64Strings);
        }

        private static List<string> GetImageAsBase64(FileInfo uFileInfo)
        {
            List<string> base64Strings = new List<string>();

            if (uFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(uFileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    ExcelDrawings drawings = worksheet.Drawings;
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (ExcelPicture picture in drawings)
                    {
                        var excelImage = picture.Image as ExcelImage;
                        var imageBytes = excelImage.ImageBytes;

                        if (imageBytes != null)
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                            {
                                Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);

                                using (MemoryStream base64Stream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    image.Save(base64Stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(base64Stream.ToArray());
                                    base64Strings.Add(base64String);
                                }

                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist");
            }

            return base64Strings;
        }

        private static void Convert2Html(FileInfo uFileInfo, List<String> base64Strings)
        {
            if (uFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(uFileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    int columnCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<html>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<head>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css\">");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</head>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<body>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<table class=\"table table-bordered\">");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");

                    //Header
                    for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++)
                    {
                        object cellValue = worksheet.Cells[1, col].Value;
                        if (cellValue != null)
                        {
                            htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<th>{cellValue}</th>");
                            Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
                        }
                    }
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");

                    int i = 0;
                    //Rows
                    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");

                        for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++)
                        {
                            object cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                            if (cellValue != null)
                            {
                                htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<td>{cellValue}</td>");
                                Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
                            }

                            //Image
                            if (col == 6)
                            {
                                htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<td><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{base64Strings[i]}\" /></td>");
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }

                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</table>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</body>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</html>");

                    string htmlTable = htmlBuilder.ToString();
                    string outputPath = @"C:\Users\Benne\Pictures\excelExport\index.html";

                    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, htmlTable);
                    Console.WriteLine("HTML-File exported");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
```