# Display Image From Excel Using .net and view using html

Tags: css, excel, image, import, export

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

namespace FileData
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string excelFilePath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\FileDemo.xlsx";

            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelFilePath);
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    int columnCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
                    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<html>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<head>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css\">");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</head>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<body>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<table class=\"table table-bordered\">");

                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++)
                    {
                        var cellValue = worksheet.Cells[1, col].Value;
                        string value = cellValue?.ToString() ?? "";
                        htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<th>{value}</th>");
                    }
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
                        for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++)
                        {
                            var cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                            string value = cellValue?.ToString() ?? "";

                            if (col == 8 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            {
                                // Display the image if the value is not empty
                                string imageFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(excelFilePath), value);
                                Console.WriteLine("Image File Path: " + imageFilePath);

                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(imageFilePath))
                                {
                                    byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath);
                                    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                                    string imageSource = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{base64Image}";
                                    Console.WriteLine(imageSource);
                                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<td><img src=\"{imageSource}\" alt=\"Image\" style=\"height: 300px; width: 300px;\"></td>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<td>No image found</td>");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                htmlBuilder.AppendLine($"<td>{value}</td>");
                            }
                        }
                        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }

                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</table>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</body>");
                    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</html>");
                    string htmlFilePath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\FileDemo.html";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(htmlFilePath, htmlBuilder.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("HTML file created successfully.");
                    Console.WriteLine($"File Path: {htmlFilePath}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

i tried this code that display data except image

Id  Name    Age Gender  Designation Phone Number    Photo
1   Ami 21  Female  B Tech          9785612345  image

i've this fields in my excel file i want to display image when i retrive data but image is not displaying with my precious code. there is one condition that you cannot take image page in excel cell for image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read data from excel with image column using c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611972/read-data-from-excel-with-image-column-using-c-sharp-net)